# Why is "where" used in this sentence?

Tags: where

A student showed me the following sentence in her English textbook. She asked me to clarify why *where* is used in the sentence. Since I cannot read Japanese, can someone please explain why? I have been taught that *where* is only used for places or [situations](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/236427/24061). In this case, it seems to be describing the noun (a type of corn, whatever it is) in more detail.

[image]

Comment: "Where" has been bleached of its locative meaning here, and is the equivalent of "in which". "Where the kernel is hard on the outside ..." is a supplementary relative clause in which "where" has "corn" as its antecedent. The meaning is "a certain type of corn in which the kernel is hard on the outside ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you hit it with the word "situation". The condition of the corn kernel is a "situation"

See use 3 & 4 here:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/situation

> 3. condition; case; plight: He is in a desperate situation.
> 4. the state of affairs; combination of circumstances: The present international situation is dangerous.

The *desparate* & *dangerous* examples should not lead one to believe that the *situation* must always be negative.

Comment: In more formal writing, you might use *wherein* in place of *where*, for which there is no doubt as to its meaning.